# Store date into db

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a string that has a date in the following format:

> Aug 12th 2019, 04:19:25 pm NY

I need to store it into mySQL db as DATETIME value.

I've attempted to convert it:

```
$newstr = strtotime($oldstr);
```

but it returns no value. I think the string is malformed. What can I do to get the values?

Comment: MySQL expects dates to be in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. You can also use the MySQL function `STR_TO_TIME()` to parse other formats.

Comment: I suggest trying with DateTime::createFromFormat, specifying the appropriate format you currently have to work with. https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: `strtotime()` returns a Unix timestamp as an integer, not a datetime. You can use `FROM_UNIXTIME()` to convert that to a date in MySQL.

Comment: It returns no value. How do you know that it doesn't? Did you output it?

Comment: @putvande: No, they didn't https://3v4l.org/0earO maybe they mean no value in database.

Comment: My bad, my string actually included NY, as in : Aug 12th 2019, 04:19:25 pm NY I suppose to indicate East coast time...

Comment: Need to do what @Naomi states.  You can use `??` for the unknown city/timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version respects the `NY` timezone.

```php
<?php

$oldstr = 'Aug 12th 2019, 04:05:55 pm NY';

$timezones = [
    'NY' => 'America/New_York',
    // add more...
];

$timezone = new \DateTimeZone($timezones[substr($oldstr, -2)]);

$date = new \DateTimeImmutable(substr($oldstr, 0, -2));
$date = $date->setTimezone($timezone);

$newstr = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// Output: 2019-08-12 10:05:55
echo $newstr;
```

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks.

Comment: Except its missing the `NY` that you made sure to point out afterwards: https://3v4l.org/rdFOV

Comment: @AbraCadaver Thanks, I added the timezone.